# Detecting libc function with IDA

Tags: ida, arm, static-analysis

I have binary than running on Arm , static and striped.

I don't know which compiler compiled this binary.

How can I identify function like `fread` `sleep` `printf` `ioctl`

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that.

Several approaches:

1. Build your own `libc` for `ARM` and then do a compare using `IDA FLIRT`, `bindiff`, `diaphora` or similar, or just use is as a reference to see how those function should look like.
2. Look for the most referenced functions, a good chance that some of them will be `libc`. After finding some, look at the neighbor functions, good chance they will be also `libc`.

IdaPython script for the most referenced functions:

```
import idautils

funcs = {}
for func_addr in Functions():
    funcs[hex(func_addr)] = len(list(idautils.XrefsTo(func_addr, 1)))

referenced_funcs = sorted(funcs.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

3. If you look for a specific `libc` function, you can try to filter the functions in your binary by features like the number of parameters, referenced strings, numeric values inside and so on.

Comment: How can I find the most referenced functions?

Comment: I added a script for that in the answer.